# Does my vertica works on in memory?

Tags: vertica

I have used Hp Vertica 7.0

It sometimes slowed down. (`select count(*) from sessions ;` **returns : 250** )

When I checked *system monitor* on  centos which the vertica is installed on ,

there is not huge load on the machine. I want to know the db is work on in memory?

it comes by default or should I set it in paramaters table?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you have 250 programs currently connected with your Vertica cluster.

Every connection uses memory and other resources, even if it is idle.

To see how many processes are active, you might go:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) as active_request_count
FROM query_requests
WHERE is_executing;
```

And, by all means, verify how many of the 250 connections / sessions are really needed, and close all sessions that are not needed.

Maybe, if you can, it's easiest to shut down and restart the database.

Good luck

Marco

Comment: thanks for answer, connections are closed in a litlle time  but news open, I want to know my vertica is in memory database ? or should I set one of parameter to do it in memory

Comment: Vertica is not an in-memory database. Vertica's strength is to work on very big volumes of data - which would not fit into memory anyway. We only use memory for the Write Optimized Store, so that we can continuously load data while the data is being queried - and consolidate the data from the Write Optimized Store into the Read Optimized Store, which is on disk, continuously in a background process. But that has nothing to do with the number of currently active sessions.